# scala - converting sql repetitive code to scala

Tags: sql, scala

i am trying to convert multi union sql code to efficient scala code,
i am a beginner so i would love to see some ideas how to solve this on an *easy* going matter?

```
items_by_source_1 as (

    select 
    day,
    segment,
    'bet' as source,
    --1 as level ,
    explode(total_items_from_bet_level_1)  as item_id 
    from data_1     
union all

    select 
    day,
    segment,
    'bet' as source,
    --1 as level ,
    explode(total_items_from_bet_level_2)  as item_id 
    from data_1
union all
    select 
    day,
    segment,
    'purchase' as source,
    --1 as level ,

    explode(total_items_from_purchase_level_1)  as item_id 
    from data_1
union all

    select 
    day,
    segment,
    'purchase' as source,
    --1 as level ,
    explode(total_items_from_purchase_level_2)  as item_id 
    from data_1
```

Comment: Seems like a trivial task involving `map` and `mkString`.

Comment: I'm confused: is that a `String` that you want to build more efficiently? Or do you want to run an equivalent of that SQL with Scala code?